# Execute your own JSONP function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JSONP , and my url(action) is returning me function called processTemplates.
Is there any way I can execute my own function instead of
processTemplates.

Something Like
_processJSONCallBack

```
    function _processOverideCallBack(actionName) {
         $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: actionName,
                async: false,
                contentType: "application/javascript",
                jsonpCallback: '_processJSONCallBack',
                dataType: "jsonp",
                error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
                if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                    alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                    alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                    alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
                } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                   alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
                } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                    alert('Time out error.');
                } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                    alert('Ajax request aborted.');
                } else {
                    alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                }
            }
        });
};
```

But when I am trying to do its throwing an exception "Requested JSON parse failed."

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support
>   synchronous operation

You are probably getting an error because you have `async: false`.

Comment: even when i am trying asynch=true its giving me same error

Comment: However , when i tried in my ajax call  success: function(response) {
          _processJSONCallBack(response);
         }. Magically it works

Answer (score 0):

You can get called with the data from a JSONP Ajax call in a much simpler fashion than you're trying to do because jQuery will do all the work for you of creating a callback function.  You can just do this by using a `success` handler:

```
function _processOverideCallBack(actionName) {
     $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: actionName,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function(data) {
                // data will be your already parsed JSONP data here
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
                    if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                    alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                    alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                    alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
                } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                   alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
                } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                    alert('Time out error.');
                } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                    alert('Ajax request aborted.');
                } else {
                    alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                }
            }
    });
};
```

Also, you cannot use `async: false` with JSONP.  That is not supported due to how JSONP requests work.  All JSONP requests must be async.

In addition, please remember that JSONP is a different type of request than a normal Ajax request and your server MUST support the JSONP type request.  You can't make a JSONP request of a normal Ajax URL.  The server must produce a JSONP formatted response.

Comment: @charlietfl - I see what you're referring to in the doc, except that the OP says that they are getting `'Requested JSON parse failed.'` from their `error` handler.  I wonder if it's only called for some errors due to the different way that jsonp works.

Comment: not sure...unless $.error is being triggered maybe? That's not the message for $.parseJson so no idea where it comes from

Comment: @charlietfl - It looks like that message comes from their own error handler which is apparently seeing `exception === 'parsererror'`.

Comment: oh yeah..i was looking in jq source...didn't notice OP messages. Wierd that they document it's not available

Answer (score 0):

jsonpCallback is the *parameter name* of the callback function when the request is built. Typically a JSONP request looks like this:

http://example.com/endpoint?**callback**=yourfunction&foo=bar

Based on your code, jQuery is probably generating something like this:

http://example.com/endpoint?**_processJSONCallBack**=yourfunction&foo=bar

Whatever API you're using doesn't know the name of your callback function because it isn't being set in the right parameter. Check the documentation to see what the callback parameter name should be. jQuery defaults to 'callback' if jsonpCallback isn't specified.